# How to cancel single request in volley after getting response?

Tags: android

I am adding more than one Json Request in Volley RequestQueue. After i get a successful response from any one request, i need to clear or delete the request to reduce memory. What should i do to delete the request?.

Comment: Could you show what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to add cancel request if tag just check the tag too.**

```
yourRequestQueue.cancelAll(new RequestQueue.RequestFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Request<?> request) {
    Log.d("DEBUG","request running: "+request.getTag().toString());
        return true;
    }
});
```